# Is there a way to do dynamic key/value parameters in url route in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am looking for a way (and hoping there is one available already) to read dynamically routed parameters in nodejs. (Like the way Zend Framework 1 default router did).

So I want to have something like this:

```
app.get('/resource/:key/:value/:anotherkey/:differentvalue', function(req, res) {
    return res.send('This will print the :differentvalue: '+req.params.anotherkey);
});
```

But then without having to define all different keys and values

Comment: Have you read this: https://github.com/visionmedia/express-params

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately that is not what I am looking for. I want to use the parameters as filters in an elasticsearch query, and they can change a lot. I don't want to define all them in the route cause I want to check them in the methods...

Comment: Is a "REST"-like URL a hard requirement? Because /shoes/adidas/model/123123/color/bluepurple/size/12/shipping/free will be tricky to keep track of.

Comment: Yeah. Fortunately I don't have to keep track for those urls because they're parsed dynamically. The thing is, imo, the resource /shoes/brand/adidas (filters index shoes where brand = adidas) and /shoes/brand/adidas/color/extremelypink (filters index shows where brand = adidas and color = extremelypink) are different, that's the main reason I'd like to see this type of filtering

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
app.get('/resource/*', function(req, res) {
    var list = req.path.split('/').slice(2); // Slice to leave off '/resource/'
    var obj {};
    async.whilst(
        function() { return list.length > 0 },
        function(callback) {
            obj[list.shift()] = list.shift();
        },
        function(err) { // return your obj here or do whatever else you need to do }
    );
});
```

Comment: Now that I've said this, req.path MIGHT return "/resource/*" rather than the actual parts.

Comment: This gives {"resource": "a"}, but this might point me in the right direction :p

Comment: This gives {"resource":"a"} when I use this resource: /resource/a/b/c/d (sorry, forgot to post that)

Comment: Oh, try slice(2). The first element is probably empty since the string starts with a slash.

Comment: Eventually I used:     
`app.get('/resource/*', function(req, res) {
    var list = req.path.split('/').slice(2);    
    var listLength = list.length;
    var obj = {};
    
    for(x=0; x<listLength; x++)
    {
     if(x % 2 == 1)
     {
      obj[list.shift()] = list.shift();
     }
    }
    
    res.json(obj);

});`

Comment: Sounds dangerous. I try to NEVER use for loops in node.js. It can be very hard to debug when they aren't working. That's why I used async in my example. There are others way to do it though, if you prefer NOT to use async. You can use recursion, for example. And just check `list.length > 0` before you do any processing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the querystring for this particular usecase.

So given a URL like this: `myapp.com/search/?filter_one=param&filter_two=param2`

And then use the URL module in node.

```
var url = require('url');
var parsed_url = url.parse(request.url, true);
var querystring_object = parsed_url.query
//{filter_one: "param", filter_two: "param2"}
//and that object is quite easier to hand off to elastic search
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'd really want to not use the querystring for this :S